# Searching with RxJava not working

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I'm trying to do a simple search UI, where the text change triggers a search in the service and that gets mapped to a ViewState. It would seem easy, but the following code doesn't work:

```
queryText.filter { it.length > 3 }
        .switchMap { service.search(it) }
        .onErrorReturn { SearchResponse(null, it.message) }
        .map { SearchViewState(items = it.items, error = it.error) }
        .startWith { SearchViewState(loading = true) }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { viewState.onNext(it) }
```

I've no idea what I did wrong, but through debugging I can see that the stream throws a NetworkOnMainThreadException and then terminates so new events are no longer processed.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: maybe `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` should be placed before making the network request? Are you using retrofit?

Comment: I tried putting it everywhere in the chain, always with the same result. And yes, the service.search() is a retrofit generated interface.

Comment: you can initialize retrofit to run all the requests on Schedulers.io, this way `.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `queryText` is the source of textchanges which happen on the main thread. Therefore `subscribeOn` has no effect on it. You should apply `subscribeOn` to the actual network call:

```
queryText.filter { it.length > 3 }
    .switchMap { 
        service.search(it)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .onErrorReturn { SearchResponse(null, it.message) }
        .map { SearchViewState(items = it.items, error = it.error) }
        .startWith ( SearchViewState(loading = true) )
    }
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe { viewState.onNext(it) }
```

In addition, I think you have to do the error recovery and state changes associated with the particular network call, otherwise a failure will stop the entire sequence.